# LibreOffice calc: How to apply multiple tables to a single chart

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'll say it right off the bat - I am a complete Excel/Calc amateur.

What I want to do is apply 3 tables, each with 2 columns of data into a chart with 1 XY-line for each.

My current data looks something like this:

```
col1 col2    col1 col2     col1 col2
8    9       8    9        8    9
10   0       10   0        10   0
2    4       2    4        2    4
8    1       8    1        8    1
82   8       82   8        82   8
```

, but I have also tried in a descending fashion:

```
col1 col2 
8    9
10   0
2    4
8    1
82   8

col1 col2
8    9
10   0
2    4
8    1
82   8

col1  col2
8    9
10   0
2    4
8    1
82   8
```

I haven't managed to make the graphs look anything like decent, and I am sure I am doing plenty wrong. How should I structure my tables in order to be able to create a nice chart/graph from it?

Note: Ignore the actual data, just made up some random numbers to display the table placement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution depends on your actual values:

1. If the **`X values`** are **identical in all three "tables"**, then:

   - just arrange the `Y value` columns side by side, keeping just the first X values column (so the columns are: `tab1.X`, `tab1.Y`, `tab2.Y`, `tab3.Y`):

     [image] will get [image]
   - select the complete, newly arranged data table (in my example: `A1:D6`);
   - create the chart:

     - Menu "`Insert`" -> "`Chart...`";
     - select "`X/Y (Scatter)`" as chart type; if the X values aren't sorted, select "`sort by X values`":

       [image]
     - click next;
     - make sure that "data series in columns" is selected as well as "First row as label":

       [image]

   That's all for this case. The result should look like this:

   [image]
2. If the **`X values` aren't identical** in all three "tables", things get difficult.

   - Copy all three "tables" completely (with X and Y columns) side by side:

     [image]
   - select the complete data table (in my example: `A1:F6`);
   - create the chart:

     - Menu "`Insert`" -> "`Chart...`";
     - select "`X/Y (Scatter)`" as chart type; if the X values aren't sorted, select "`sort by X values`" (as above):
     - click next;
     - make sure that "data series in columns" is selected and "First row as label" is **not** selected; click next;
     - **tell Calc which columns hold the X values and which the Y values**. By default, Calc will try to tread each column as X value column:

       [image]
     - **First, remove the data ranges that point to X values**: in the "`Data series`" list box, select "`Column C`" and remove it using the "`Remove`" button beneath the list box; do the same with "`Column E`". Now, the wizard should look like this:

       [image]
     - **Then, for "`Column D`" and "`Column F`", set the correct X value range**. To do so:

       - select `Column D`" in the "`Data series`" List box and then the "`X values...`" entry from the "`Data ranges`" list box:

         [image]
       - change the range so it points to `C2:C6`:

         [image]
       - repeat both steps for the "`Column F`" data range.

   The result will be an X/Y chart with three data ranges and different X values:

   [image]